# Apply CSS3 Transition To Some Transforms (translate3d) but Not Others (rotate)

Tags: css, transform, transition

I'd like to define a class whose CSS3 transition is only applied to the translate3d transform, and not any other transform (rotate, translate, etc). Is this possible? If so, what's the syntax? Something like this:

```
.animatedMarker {
    transition: transform:translate3d 1s linear; 
    /* transition is only applied to translate3d transformation, so rotate, translate, etc. won't be animated */
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you could add a container to that element and then separate animations, but it's kinda hacky

Comment: I don't think so, but I'd love to be proven incorrect. I think applying the specific transforms via animation keyframes could be a good alternative.

Comment: I ended up using a container element (div), applying the transition to its transform property and a child element (img) with no transition and set the rotation on the child. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 3):

You can not transition only translate3d, however you can keep the rest unaltered:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(45deg) rotate(23deg);
```

and on hover

```
transform: translate3d(100px, 0, 0) skew(45deg) rotate(23deg);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yeuxQ/1/

Comment: +1 A lot of repetition, unfortunately, but I certainly don't see any other way to do it with transitions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately I need to change both the rotate and the translate3d. I'm considering having a containing div that sets the translate3d with a transition and a child img that specifies the rotation without a transition.